# How to generate content index for OpenXML

Tags: openxml

I'm generating OOXML documents programatically with Apache POI, and one of my purposes is generate the content index of the document (as if we click on references > content table on Microsoft Office 2007).

I've been reading about this topic and looking the internal file of a docx document (document.xml). My conclusion scares me.

In order to calculate in which page will be a specific text of the document (contained in a  tag inside a  tag inside a

tag), it seems to me that I need to know the sort of font used for every text/table before it (and likely properties like bold, italic...), size of font, top and bottom margins of each page and any other "size-related" information, then calculate the number of twips that the document will have between the very first paragraph of the document (or at least from the last pagebreak) and the text I'm trying to know in which page will be...

As you can see, the process I'm figuring out is a bit awkward (or a lot) so I hope there is a much easier way to generate the content index or at least to calculate in which page a specific text will fall in. Do anyone has ideas about how to calculate this?!?!.

Call me lazy but I don't want to calculate all this stuff :s.

PD: Excuse me for my poor english, hope you understand my question.